# How do I remove the side margins when using PreferenceScreen

Tags: android-layout, switchpreference

[image: PreferenceScreen Leaving margin]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<SwitchPreference
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:key="some_key"
    android:title="@string/some_string"
    android:dialogTitle="@string/dialog_string"
    android:persistent="true"
    />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

How do I remove the "side margins"?